# Positions of the maximum in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to retrieve the positions (row, column) of the maximum value in the dataframe. How can I do?

Comment: Hi Mat, is your dataframe all numbers? Is it possible to provide a small example and intended output?

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({

         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],

})
```

First if necessary get only numbers by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
```

For return first max value in DataFrame use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
print (df.stack().idxmax())
(2, 'C')
```

If performance is important get indices by compare by max value with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and get first value by indexing:

```
r, c = np.where(df == df.values.max())
print ((df.index[r[0]], df.columns[c[0]]))
(2, 'C')
```

---

If need all max values:

```
s = df.stack()
print (s.index[s == s.max()].tolist())
[(2, 'C'), (3, 'E')

print (list(zip(df.index[r], df.columns[c])))
[(2, 'C'), (3, 'E')]
```